# Can a quotient of a polynomial ring by $n-1$ polynomials make $n$ variables $m$th powers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, finitely-generated, krull-dimension

Let $K$ be a field, consider the polynomial ring in $n$ variables $R = K[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$ and let $F_1, \ldots, F_{n-1} \in R$ be arbitrary given polynomials. Let $S$ be the quotient ring $R/(F_1, \ldots, F_{n-1})$ and assume $S \neq 0$. For a fixed integer $m > 1$, is it possible that the residue classes of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ in $S$ are all $m$-th powers?

I conjecture that the answer should be no (i.e. that for any choice of $F_1, \ldots, F_{n-1}$ and for any $m > 1$ one will have that at least one of the residue classes of the $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ is not an $m$-th power) and that this should use little more than the fact that $S$ has Krull dimension at least 1 (by the height theorem), but I cannot make it precise. Any ideas?

In the case where the characteristic of $K$ divides $m$ I might already have a proof of this conjecture; I am mainly interested in having a proof or counterexample in characteristic $0$.

Comment: Which of the data are your input precisely? It is clear that for $n=1$ the answer is *no*. Are you looking for an example of *some* field $K$ and *some* natural number $n$ and *some* polynomials and *some* $m>1$ such that the residue classes of the $X_i$ are all $m$-th powers?(Or a proof that no such example exists?)

Comment: @Servaes Indeed my conjecture is that no such example exists (i.e. for no field $K$, no values of $n$ and no values of $m$), so I would be happy with a proof of this or a counterexample. Perhaps a distinction between the case where the characteristic of $K$ is or is not coprime to $m$ might be desirable, but otherwise I would hope the answer does not depend too much on the field $K$ or the number $m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In characteristic zero, the primitive element theorem makes it easy to construct counterexamples for any $n$ and $m$. Consider the extension $K(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\subseteq K(X_1^{\frac{1}{m}},\ldots,X_n^{\frac{1}{m}})$ which has degree $m^n$. Let $\alpha$ be a primitive element for this extension. Then, $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are all $m$-th perfect powers in $R[\alpha]$ ; we can write each $X_k$ in the form $\frac{N_k(\alpha)}{D_k}$ where $N_k\in R[X]$ and $D_k\in R\setminus \lbrace 0\rbrace$. For a suitable denominator $D$ (one that is a multiple of each $D_k$, say), each $X_k$ will be of the form $P_k(\frac{\alpha}{D})$ where $P_k\in R$. Replacing $X_k$ with $\frac{X_k}{\alpha}$ if necessary, one can ensure that $P_k$ has zero as a constant term. Let $\beta=\frac{\alpha}{D}$ and let $M(X_1,\ldots,X_n,\beta)$ be its minimal polynomial.  If $B$ is any polynomial in $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ such that $F_1=M(X_1,\ldots,X_n,B(X_1,\ldots,X_n))$ is nonzero and irreducible, in the quotient ring $\frac{R}{(F_1)}$, we have that the residue classes of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are all $m$-th perfect powers.

Here is an example that shows how it works for $n=m=2$ : we can take $\alpha=\sqrt{X_1}+\sqrt{X_2}$, then $\alpha^2=X_1+X_2+2\sqrt{X_1X_2}$ so
$(\alpha^2-(X_1+X_2))^2-4X_1X_2=0$, and

$$
\sqrt{X_1}=\frac{\alpha^3-(X_2+3X_1)\alpha}{2(X_2-X_1)},
\sqrt{X_2}=\frac{\alpha^3-(X_1+3X_2)\alpha}{2(X_1-X_2)}
$$

Next, let $\beta=\frac{\alpha}{X_2-X_1}$ ; then $(\beta^2-(X_1+X_2)(X_2-X_1)^2)^2=4X_1X_2(X_2-X_1)^4$ and $\sqrt{X_1}=\frac{(X_2-X_1)^2\beta^3-(X_2+3X_1)\beta}{2}$, $\sqrt{X_2}=\frac{(X_1-X_2)^2\beta^3-(X_1+3X_2)\beta}{2}$

If we take $B(X_1,X_2)=1$, we see that in the ring $\frac{R}{(F_1)}$ with $F_1=(1-(X_1+X_2)(X_2-X_1)^2)^2-4X_1X_2(X_2-X_1)^4$, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both perfect squares.

Comment: there's a counterexample for $n=2$?? Wouldn't $F_1$ have to divide $X_1^2$ and $X_2^2$?

Comment: @mathworker21 Why should $F_1$ divide $X_k^2$ ? We want $X_k$ to be a square, we don't want its square to be $0$.

Comment: I meant $F_1$ divide $X_k(X_k-1)$.

Comment: @mathworker21 I still don't see your point : the OP wants $X_k$ to be a $m$-th power in the quotient ring, which means that $X_k-E^m$ is in the ideal for some $E$. When $m=n=2$, this translates as : $F_1$ divides $X_k-E^2$ for some $E$, and not $F_1 | X_k(X_k-1)$ (which would mean that $X_k^2=X_k$ in the quotient ring).

Comment: Wow, I completely misread problem. Lemme read your solution now...

Comment: I did not yet get how to obtain the $P_k$ in general. I can see how when $N_k$ would not have a constant term; but what if it does?

Comment: @Bib-lost The constant-term changes nothing and the passage from $\frac{N_k}{D}$ to $P_k$ is trivial : if $N=\sum_{k=0}^{r} n_kX^k$, then $\frac{N}{D}(X)=P(\frac{X}{\delta})$ where $\sum_{k=0}^r n_k\frac{\delta^k}{D} X^k$. For $P$ to be in $R[X]$ it suffices to take $\delta$ to be a multiple of $D$. If you want a $\delta$ to work for several $\frac{N}{D}$'s at once, you can take the lcm of the denominators.

Comment: I am still not understanding how you resolve this. If $n_0 \neq 0$, then the constant term of $P$ is still $n_0 \frac{\delta^0}{D} = \frac{n_0}{D}$, regardless of $\delta$. Perhaps I am missing something trivial

Comment: @Bib-lost This is something that can easily be fixed indeed : rather than write $X_k$ as a polynomial directly, write $\frac{X_k}{\alpha}$ as a $Q_k(\alpha)$. and then you have $X_k=P_k(\alpha)$ where $P_k=XQ_k$ has constant term zero. I'm adding a small explanation about that in the answer